# how to highlight menu link of current page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

this is a very common problem, but i couldn't find any solutions to my situation.
i'm making a pretty big website with hundred of pages, so i created a header page and a footer page that are the same in every page. now i want to highlight the menu button of the current page, but my menu is in the header that i include in every page using `<?php include("header.php");?>` so everything i try doesn't work.
i tried this [method](http://blog.huidesign.com/automatically-highlight-current-page-in-navigation-with-css-jquery/) but works only if there's the menu code in every page(so without using php include).
any suggestions?

this is the code of my menu bar

```css
nav {
    height: 40px;
    background: black;
    border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
}
#navblock {
    margin-left: 160px;  
}
nav ul{
    list-style: none; 
    position: relative; 
    display: inline-table;
    }
nav ul li{ 
    float: left; 
    font-size: 20px;
    }
nav ul li:hover {
    background: #666;
    }
nav ul li:hover a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    }
nav ul li a {
    display:block; 
    padding-top: 6px; 
    padding-left: 30px; 
    padding-right: 30px; 
    padding-bottom: 6px; 
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    }
nav ul ul {
    display: none; 
    background: #101010; 
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    width: auto;
    position: absolute; 
    z-index: 1;
    top: 40px;}
nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display:block;
    }
nav ul ul li {
    float: none; 
    position: relative; 
    font-size: 14px; 
    margin-left: 0px;
    }
nav ul ul li a:hover {
    background: #666;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<nav>
    <div id="navblock">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/anime/index.html">Anime</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/anime/listaepisodi.html">Lista episodi Anime</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/anime/episodio00.html">episodio00</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="/serietv/index.html">Serie TV</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Lista completa Serie TV</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Cerca Anime</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: The example you linked to should work just fine, PHP doesn't care if the code is in the same page or included/required. Just make the class="active" or class="highlight" conditional based on which page you're on. If you're having problems please try to incorporate some solution and post that code here.

Comment: i know it should work, but it doesn't! if i write the code in every single page it works just like in this example http://blog.huidesign.com/wp-content/demo/highlight_navigation/childNav/index.html           but if i write the code in one page and i use php include to include that page in all the others it doesn't highlight anything

Comment: then please post the code where you've tried to apply that solution so we can see where the error is.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xsvsvefL/1/         here's the code i modified, as i said, it works, but only if i put it in every page.

Comment: thank you guys, i resolved the problem. the problem was that to test my pages i left i few menu links blank (<a href=""></a>), and it highlighted those, but by filling them there are no more problems

Answer (score 2):

try this script..

```
var url = window.location;
$('a[href="'+url+'"]').parent('li').addClass('active');
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you [include some explanation along with it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/159034) to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and readers need to understand how it once worked.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion it will be shown in my all next answers. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can highlight the current page using JavaScript. Using `window.location.href`, JavaScript gives you the url of the currently loaded page. So, on window load, you can do something like this (assuming jQuery installed):

```
var pg = window.location.href.substring(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/"));
$("a[href=" + pg + "]").parent('li').addClass('active');
```

Of course, this is also assuming that you do have a css class called `active` pre-defined which takes care of decorating the active link!

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing from your PHP page, take one $active class and asign value that from PHP file, i will explain you with example :-

You are in home page then just set $active class as following.

```
$active = "home";
```

Now in common header file make condition on each

like following :-

```
<ul>
    <li class="<?php echo ($active == "home") ? "active" : ""; ?>"><a href="/index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li class="<?php echo ($active == "anime") ? "active" : ""; ?>"><a href="/anime/index.html">Anime</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/anime/listaepisodi.html">Lista episodi Anime</a></li>
            <li><a href="/anime/episodio00.html">episodio00</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="<?php echo ($active == "serietv") ? "active" : ""; ?>"><a href="/serietv/index.html">Serie TV</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Lista completa Serie TV</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Cerca Anime</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```