# Highlight current PHP page in menu using Javascript CSS

Tags: javascript, php, css

This seems like a common problem, but I haven't found a solution yet. I would like to highlight the current page in my menu. Javascript and CSS seems to be the best option but I can't get it to work for pages including a PHP query.

HTML

```
<ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
<li><a href="about.php">About / Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="portfolios.php?page=travel-nature">Travel &amp; Nature</a></li>
<li><a href="portfolios.php?page=video">Video</a></li>
<li><a href="portfolios.php?page=editorial">Editorial</a></li>
<li><a href="portfolios.php?page=corporate">Corporate</a></li>
</ul>
```

Javascript

```
<script>
$(function(){
$("a").each(function() {
if ($(this).prop("href") === window.location) {
  $(this).addClass("current");
}
});
});
</script>
```

It works for 'about.php' but not for any of the 'portfolios.php' pages.

I've also added

```
<script>
document.write(window.location);
</script>
```

to a couple of pages and it returns the full path including PHP query, so I know `window.location` works.
I know there's probably an answer on here already but I can't find it!

**Solved**
What was missing, which is obvious if you know what you are doing, but not to me, was `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` at the end of the portfolios.php page, where it was present on the about.php page.

Comment: `Window.location` is actually a [`Location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) object so you can use it as one. The fact that what you're doing works is because `Location.toString()` will return the full URL.

Comment: try comparing to `window.location.href`

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33848734/how-to-highlight-menu-link-of-current-page?rq=1

Comment: Forgive me if I'm  missing something obvious (I could well be) - I couldn't see a solution in that link, although it does seem to be that same problem. Also, `window.location` and `window.location.href` both return the full URL, so I don't think that's the problem. Does it matter where the script is placed on the page? The HTML and script above are in a file called header.php which is included in about.php and portfolios.php. I don't know if that makes any difference to anything?

Answer (score 1):

Try comparing to `window.location.href`

```
$("a").filter(function() {
  return this.href === window.location.href;    
}).addClass("current");
```

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately. Same result...

Comment: Are any of those links being added by javascript after your code runs?

Comment: No, the code appears on the page as it listed above,

Comment: so are other parameters other than `page` used in url also?

Comment: No, it's just as it appears, so the full URL would be http://theomoye.co.uk/portfolios.php?page=editorial for example.

Answer (score 0):

your if condition has to be changed

```
$("a").each(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("current");
    if ($(this).attr("href") == location.href.substr(location.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)) {
      $(this).addClass("current");
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm afraid that hasn't worked either.

Answer (score 0):

The strict comparison `===` is breaking your logic. If you do the strict comparison on `window.loation.toString()`, it works.  Or, you could compare loosely, with `==` instead, and the type conversion won't break the comparison.

Comment: It was meant to be `==` but it doesn't seem to make a difference.